# Python - Find the dollar and cent

Tags: python

Assume that price is an integer variable whose value is the price (in US currency) in cents of an item. Write a statement that prints the value of price in the form "X dollars and Y cents" on a line by itself. So, if the value of price was 4321, your code would print "43 dollars and 21 cents". If the value was 501 it would print "5 dollars and 1 cents". If the value was 99 your code would print "0 dollars and 99 cents".

I have done like this:

```
print (price/100,"dollars and",price%100, "cents")
```

Result Ex: 2314

```
23.14 dollars and 14 cents
```

How can I make the result look like:

```
23 dollars and 14 cents
```

Comment: you can use `price//100` to keep the integer part

Comment: your code works for me , printing 23 dollars and 14 cents

Comment: @Deepaklal That's because you must be using Python2 and OP must be using Python3

Comment: @Julien Yes, you are right, python3 it prints as floating point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input:

```
x = 4321

print (x/100),'dollars and',int(100*((x/100.00)-(x/100))),'cents'
```

Output:

```
43 dollars and 21 cents
```

Comment: Did you ever test this print statement? Just looking at the placement of parentheses leaves me scratching my head.

Comment: I did mate, was using python 2.7 at the time. What specifically is causing confusion?

Comment: Oh, I jumped to conclusions. I was trying to match up the starting '(' and didn't see one at the end as I would in Python 3, OK - please forgive me.

Comment: Edit your answer (mention python 2.7?) and I will be able to upvote. Learned a lesson here - don't jump to conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
price=2314

print (price/100,"dollars and",price%100, "cents")
```

This will output:

```
(23, 'dollars and', 14, 'cents')
```

Comment: This may work for you in Python2 but will not work in Python3 which the OP must be using.

Answer (score 0):

The OP was on the right track; in Python 3+ both

```
print (price//100,"dollars and",price%100, "cents")
```

and

```
print (math.floor(price/100),"dollars and",price%100, "cents")
```

give the desired result.

---

Here is a direct string handling attack that incorporates testing tactics:

```
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*
# Desc: Print Dollars and Cents
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*

def formatPrint(cents):
    centsStr = str(cents)
    d, c = centsStr[:-2], centsStr[-2:]
    if cents > 99:
        print(d + ' dollars and ' + c + ' cents')
    else:
        print('0 dollars and ' + c + ' cents')
    return 


x = [0,7,23,111,4321,54321]

for ndx in range(0, len(x)):
    print (x[ndx], ':')
    formatPrint(x[ndx])
```